# How to read an XML file in Mule Anypoint Studio after invoking an HTTP endpoint?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I am new to **Anypoint Studio** and I am trying to create a flow that will have an **HTTP** connector and an endpoint and when a user invokes the http endpoint then the application will load the contents of an **XML** file, will convert then to **JSON** and will return the **JSON** back in the **HTTP** Response.

My flow configuration looks like this

```
<flow name="test-flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HttpListenerConfiguration" path="/read" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:response-builder statusCode="200">
                <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
            </http:response-builder>
        </http:listener>
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="xml/test.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="org.mule.examples.Catalog" doc:name="XML to Object"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer sourceClass="org.mule.examples.Catalog" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

Of course it doesn't work. I get a

`SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.`

which I assume is coming from the fact that `<file:inbound-endpoint...>` needs to be as a source in the flow.

Any suggestions on how can I read a file after an **HTTP** endpoint is invoked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly assumed, file:inbound-endpoint can only act as a message source. Thus to achieve what you want you can use the [mule module requester](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/). HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [requester module](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester). It will allow you to load the file at any point in the flow. You can read more about it in this [blogpost](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use XML to Json inbuilt transformer in to convert it to a Json object.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="test-flow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file is on the classpath, you might try `<parse-template location="xml/test.xml">` instead of your `<file:inbound-endpoint />`

The parse-template processor comes in handy surprisingly often.  The User's Guide also has a nice [reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a java component to read the  content of the file and use that component in the flow.

Example:

public class FileReaderComponent implements Callable, Initialisable {

```
private String filePath;

public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

@Override
public void initialise() throws InitialisationException {
    if (filePath == null || filePath.equals("")) {
        throw new InitialisationException(MessageFactory.createStaticMessage("FilePath property has to be set"), this);
    }
}
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle Exception
    }

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          content.append(line);

        } 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle Exception
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }


    return content.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: That works but the requester module is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

As many suggested in above, you can use java component or some kind of parse template.

We also had same kind of requirement  , we used the expression component to read the file from particular location